# Azure App Service Plan cannot be changed

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-service-plan

I have an App Service plan on which we have deployed some applications.
For the needs of reorganizing server and applications I wanted to rename the service plan which was in a standard resource group "Default-Web-WestEurope-blablabla".

Given that an App service plan cannot be renamed I have during the time created another resource group and gradually moved all my apps and services (Storage, Database ,etc.) inside the new resource group. Also the old App Service plan has been moved to the new resource group.

The scope was to have everything inside a new resource group and then create a new App Service plan where to move all the app services in the previous one by using the "Change App Service plan feature".

However I have discovered, after having created a new App service plan, that when I try to hit the "Change App Service plan feature" option, the answer is "No App Service plan found"!

[image]

How can I move all the resource between the two App Service plan?

**EDIT**:

I have tried by using Powershell and I get a a reason.

> Set-AzureRmWebApp : Cannot change the site xxxxx to the App Service
>   Plan XXXXX due to hosting constraints. At line:1 char:1

Comment: are those service plan in the same region? are they of the same "level" (both standard or both basic)?

Comment: Yes they are. By searching on the internet I have found an article that says that it depends on the webspace internal configuration. In other words this operation can't be done if the original app service plan is in a different web space. Which is, for instance, exactly my case.

Comment: Please see [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/341e8fd0-9c43-4063-82a7-a219dd765d88/no-app-service-plans-found?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview#c5d3c690-4d2b-4f68-90c4-688638a24710) for the long discussion

Comment: thanks, so thats the stamp limitation. well, cant help that I guess

Answer (score 4):

> In other words this operation can't be done if the original app service plan is in a different web space.

Yes, you are right. There is a limit when move an app to a different App Service plan. The resource group in the limit is the initial resource group when you create your App Service Plan.

```
Only valid plans (in the same resource group and geographical location) are shown.
```

For your issue, you could create a new App Service Plan in your original resource group. After finished the web app move operation, you could move all the resources to the new resource group.

If you moved your web app to the new resource group, [Web App backup and restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-backup) is a good choice to copy all the contents and configurations from your old Web App to a new Web App.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I just deleted the resources causing this issue and redeployed those resources.